# Passing an array of object to laravel api resource showing Attempt to read property "code" on array

Tags: laravel, resources, guzzle

I am building an API with laravel. I want to pass this array of object through and API resource so that I can display only code and name but I am getting error:

> Attempt to read property "code" on array

This is the data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 132,
        "code": "560",
        "name": "Page"
    },
    {
        "id": 133,
        "code": "304",
        "name": "Mobile"
    }
  ]
```

This is my controller function that gets the data from API and push it to the API resource:

```
public function getBanks(Utils $utils)
{

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer xxxxxxx',
    ];

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'my-api' , [
        'verify' => false,
        'headers' => $headers
        ]);
    $banks = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    return $utils->message("success", BankResource::collection($banks["data"])  , 200);

}
```

This is my API resource function:

```
public function toArray(Request $request): array
{
    return [
      "code" => $this->code,
      "bank" => $this->bank
    ];
}
```

Comment: what line does it say the error is coming from?

Comment: are you sure you copied the correct error? if anything the error should be `undefined property $bank` since your data contains a `code` property but it is missing the `bank` property

Comment: @Hockic Yes I copied the correct error

Comment: put "dd($this);" in toArray function and please share results, or may be you found the error by your self

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by converting $banks["data"] to std class

```
 public function getBanks(Utils $utils)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . env("_KEY") ,
        ];
        try {
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.xxxxxx.com/v3/banks' , [
                'verify' => false,
                'headers' => $headers
                ]);
            $banks = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
            return $utils->message("success", BankResource::collection(json_decode(json_encode($banks["data"])))  , 200);

        }catch (\Throwable $e) {
            // Do something with your exception
            return $utils->message("error","Network Error. Please Try again" , 400);
        }
    }
```